# Cocos2D call method certain amount of times per second?

Tags: ios, methods, cocos2d-iphone, intervals, schedule

I am using Cocos2D 2.0 and my issue at the moment is scheduling a method a certain amount of times per second.

Pretty much what I am basically trying to do is:

```
1. If score is 10 or less, call the method 5 times a second
2. If score is 11 or more, call the method 10 times a second
```

So for the interval, I have tried doing 1/5 or 1/10 respectively and it hasn't worked. Is there a certain way I should be doing this using this call?

```
[self schedule:@selector() interval:];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `schedule:interval:` will do the trick. Problem here is that `1/10` and `1/5` are fractions defined with two integer literals, so by C convention the integer division is applied and result is 0.

Try with `[self schedule:@selector(yourMethod) interval:1.0/10]` and it should work.

It's useful to note that `schedule:` method automatically updates the interval if you reschedule the same selector, you don't need to unschedule it before.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that I don't have to unschedule it each time I wanted to update the interval.

Comment: Turns out another reason why I want having this issue was because I was not using a float in my method but an int. Stupid mistake on my part! :)

Comment: That's what I wrote: "Problem here is that 1/10 and 1/5 are fractions defined with two integer literals, so by C convention the integer division is applied and result is 0."

Comment: By writing `1.0/10` instead one of them is a float so result is calculated correctly (and it is `0.1`)

Answer (score 1):

I Think you can achive the goal by using this

```
if(score <= 10){
[self schedule:@selector(yourMethod) interval:0.5f];
```

`}else{
[self schedule:@selector(yourMethod) interval:0.10f];
}`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try this too later and see if it fixes my issue.